# Cypress integration with github and allure

Tags: report, cypress, allure

Hi so i have integrated cypress with github actions and all my test codes are executed on github. I wanted to know if there is way to integrate my repo with allure-reports as well. So once my code is executed i want my reports to be generated in allure dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

FYI , I have successfully used this library https://github.com/Shelex/cypress-allure-plugin

It's working perfectly well with GH actions

Comment: thanks i will check and update you

Comment: can you share me your .yaml file?